# How to detect which Yes/No/Cancel button was clicked in a Messagebox

Tags: c++, messagebox, vcl

I am using a VCL Forms application in C++ Builder.

How do I display a Messagebox with Yes/No/Cancel buttons and then detect if the yes, the no or the cancel button is pressed.

Here is my code:

```c++
if(MessageBox(NULL, "Test message", "test title",  MB_YESNOCANCEL) == IDYES) {}
```

I have included the following:

```c++
#include <windows.h>
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
E2034 Cannot convert 'char const[13]' to 'const wchar_t *'

E2342 Type mismatch in parameter 'lpText' (wanted 'const wchar_t *', got 'const char *')
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to use wide characters in the call to `MessageBox` and you need to store the result in a variable, before working out what to do next.

```c++
const int result = MessageBox(NULL, L"Test message", L"test title",  MB_YESNOCANCEL);

switch (result)
{
case IDYES:
    // Do something
    break;
case IDNO:
    // Do something
    break;
case IDCANCEL:
    // Do something
    break;
}
```

You should read the documentation for [MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you are using ANSI strings where UNICODE (actually wide character, but let's ignore details for the moment) strings are required. Try this:

```c++
if(MessageBox(NULL, L"Test message", L"test title",  MB_YESNOCANCEL) == IDYES)
```

Even better, to ensure that your strings are conforming to your app settings, you can use:

```c++
if(MessageBox(NULL, _T("Test message"), _T("test title"),  MB_YESNOCANCEL) == IDYES)
```

This will result in wide (`wchar_t*`) strings being used in UNICODE builds, and narrow (`char*`) strings in non-UNICODE builds (see '_TCHAR maps to' part in the [Project Options](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C++_%28Shared_Options%29)).

For more details, see [Embarcadero Documentation Wikis](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/TCHAR_Mapping).

Comment: Thanks. What is the best way to detect if the yes, no or the cancel button is pressed? Do I place the Messagebox result into a variable and then use an if statement to detect the button, or some other method?

Comment: If you need to handle all 3 cases differently then yes, you should store it in a variable and use `if` or `switch-case` statement to react accordingly. Otherwise, your code is fine, but then the question is why not just have MB_YESNO.

Comment: I am just thinking of other situations where I might like more than two message buttons. Do I return the variable from the messagebox into an int, or is there a specific type for messagebox returns?

Comment: pressing F1 will show the documentation :). As I said, I don't use C++ Builder, so I have also looked up all of this on Google.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable — I think — something like multybit characters, but you need to check against the documentation with your compiler.

Answer (score 0):

All previous answers are obsolete for VS 2015. In my case:

```c++
MessageBox(NULL, L"Test message", L"test title",  MB_YESNOCANCEL);
```

doesn't work, because of first argument excess. Error output was:

> to many arguments in functional call.

If I write:

```c++
const int result = MessageBox( L"Test message", L"test title",  MB_YESNOCANCEL); //Without NULL

switch (result)
{
case IDYES:
    // Do something
    break;
case IDNO:
    // Do something
    break;
case IDCANCEL:
    // Do something
    break;
}
```

It will work!